# Reading avro files from s3 with spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I want to read Avro files from s3 with Spark structured streaming API. You can find information about doing it with Kafka, but I can't find anything for s3. The problem here is that I don't know what format to set. Here's my simple code:

```java
 Dataset<Row> baseDataSet = sparkSession            
    .readStream()                              
    .format("?") //What this format should be?                            
    .schema(new StructType()                   
            .add("value", "binary"))           
    .load("s3://path/to/streaming/key")    
    .select(col("value"))
    .map(value -> {//do avro deserialization},Encoders.kryo(//deserialization class))                                    
    .writeStream() 
    .trigger(ProcessingTime.create(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    .format("console")
    .outputMode("update")
    .start();
```

I understand that avro is still not implemented in the structured streaming api. But what format should I put in order to read binary data and then deserialize it in whatever way I want(in the map function).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [third-party package for avro](https://spark-packages.org/package/databricks/spark-avro). You can download the jar and use it with spark to load avro files directly by specifying `format("com.databricks.spark.avro")`.

Currently there is no way to read whole file in structured streaming to apply deserialization later.

However if you still want to have custom deserializer you can develop a custom data source by implementing `trait DataSourceRegister`. As example  you might want to check [spark-avro package](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/branch-4.0/src/main/scdala/com/databricks/spark/avro/DefaultSource.scala).

In case if you need to convert input data to byte array you can use something like this:

```
session
    .readStream()
    .textFile("path-to-folder")
    .as(Encoders.BINARY())
    .map(bytesToStringMapper, Encoders.STRING())
    .writeStream()
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
    .format("text")
    .option("path", "path-to-folder")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "path-to-folder")
    .queryName("test-query")
    .start();
```

Current approach loads files as text line by line though. It means that `bytesToStringMapper` receives single line as byte array and converts it to string.

Comment: How can you add this third party package to a glue job??

Comment: Using `--extra-jars` argument (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html)